# Why doesn't managed_shared_memory::find() return the same address as managed_shared_memory::construct()?

Tags: boost-interprocess

I'm having a problem where I am using Boost Interprocess to write some values to shared memory using managed_shared_memory::construct() then in another process trying to read those values using managed_shared_memory::find() but it is not coming back with the same address that was created using construct().

I took the sample code from the Boost Interprocess documentation for [Creating named shared memory objects](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_named_interprocess) and split into two different programs and the same thing is happening.
**interprocess_write.cpp**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   typedef std::pair<double, int> MyType;

   if(argc == 1){  //Parent process
       shared_memory_object::remove ("MySharedMemory");

      //Construct managed shared memory
      managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

      //Create an object of MyType initialized to {0.0, 0}
      MyType *instance = segment.construct<MyType>
         ("MyType instance")  //name of the object
         (0.0, 0);            //ctor first argument

      //Create an array of 10 elements of MyType initialized to {0.0, 0}
      MyType *array = segment.construct<MyType>
         ("MyType array")     //name of the object
         [10]                 //number of elements
         (0.0, 0);            //Same two ctor arguments for all objects

      //Create an array of 3 elements of MyType initializing each one
      //to a different value {0.0, 0}, {1.0, 1}, {2.0, 2}...
      float float_initializer[3] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 };
      int   int_initializer[3]   = { 0, 1, 2 };

      MyType *array_it = segment.construct_it<MyType>
         ("MyType array from it")   //name of the object
         [3]                        //number of elements
         ( &float_initializer[0]    //Iterator for the 1st ctor argument
         , &int_initializer[0]);    //Iterator for the 2nd ctor argument

      std::cout << array << ":" << instance << ":" << array_it << std::endl;

      //Check child has destroyed all objects
      if(segment.find<MyType>("MyType array").first ||
         segment.find<MyType>("MyType instance").first ||
         segment.find<MyType>("MyType array from it").first)
         return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**interprocess_read.cpp**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
       using namespace boost::interprocess;
       typedef std::pair<double, int> MyType;

  //Open managed shared memory
  managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");

  std::pair<MyType*, managed_shared_memory::size_type> res;

  //Find the array
  res = segment.find<MyType> ("MyType array");
  //Length should be 10
  if(res.second != 10) return 1;

  std::cout << res.first << ":";

  //Find the object
  res = segment.find<MyType> ("MyType instance");
  //Length should be 1
  if(res.second != 1) return 1;

  std::cout << res.first << ":";

  //Find the array constructed from iterators
  res = segment.find<MyType> ("MyType array from it");
  //Length should be 3
  if(res.second != 3) return 1;

  std::cout << res.first << std::endl;

  //We're done, delete all the objects
  segment.destroy<MyType>("MyType array");
  segment.destroy<MyType>("MyType instance");
  segment.destroy<MyType>("MyType array from it");
}
```

When I ran the interprocess_write program I got the following output:

> 0x1260128:0x12600d8:0x1260208

But when I run the interprocess_read program I get:

> 0x2ad0128:0x2ad00d8:0x2ad0208

Is there something missing that has to be done in interprocess_read to make it pull the correct addresses out of shared memory?

Comment: I don't want to presume, but it sounds like you expect the object in shared memory to show up at the same virtual memory address in both processes. That's not happening by default, and you don't want to try to force it. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: I don't even remeber. I moved on from that problem months ago.